# Dúvida estrutura switch Javascript

Tags: javascript

Nesse exemplo.

```
switch(numero {
          case '0':
          case '1':
          case '2':
          case '3':
          case '4':
          case '5':
          case '6':
          case '7':
          case '8':
          case '9': console.log('Case 9');
          break;
```

A instrução está caindo no case 9, quando o numero = '2', sei que isso acontece por que não foi utilizada a instrução break no case '2', mas por que isso acontece, já que que '2' é diferente de '9'?

Comment: Switch é efeito cascata por padrão em javascript, algumas línguas não são. Sendo assim não é um erro de código, é só comportamento padrão que você tem de se adaptar em cada linguagem. É tipo inglês e português, coisas mudam de ordem e não há nada de errado com isto, entretanto se quisermos fazer da forma correta é nós que temos de aprender e executar da maneira de cada qual.

Answer (score 0):

Paulo, o switch tem exatamente esse comportamento, quando a instrução break é omitida, assim que que o switch encontra um condição válida, ele entrará nas demais, mesmo que as condições não sejam atendidas... Ele segue até o final ou até encontrar uma instrução de break.

Execute o exemplo abaixo, e verá que conforme o FOR é executado, a quantidade de informações diminui:

```
for (let numero = 0; numero < 10; numero++ ) {
    switch (numero) {
        case 0: console.log('Case 0');
        case 1: console.log('Case 1');
        case 2: console.log('Case 2');
        case 3: console.log('Case 3');
        case 4: console.log('Case 4');
        case 5: console.log('Case 5');
        case 6: console.log('Case 6');
        case 7: console.log('Case 7');
        case 8: console.log('Case 8');
        case 9: console.log('Case 9');
        break;
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

---

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque, se colocar dois ou mais `case` sem um `break` seria como "se for 0, ou 1, ou 2, ou 3...." ou seja, como se fosse uma sequência de valores com "or". Como se fosse um comando `if` assim:

`if (numero==0 || numero==1...)`

Se quiser separa cada opção, acrescente um comando para cada uma:

```
switch(numero {
          case '0': 
               console.log('Case 0');
               break;
          case '1': 
               console.log('Case 1');
               break;
          ... etc ...
```

Comment: Nesse caso, se entrar `numero = '0'`, todos os `console.log` serão executados. Não me pareceu ser o comportamento que desejava colocar.

Comment: verdade @AndersonCarlosWoss , faltou `break` :(  corrigido